# How to select a menu item in ExtJS Using Javascript?

Tags: extjs

I have a Menu bar which can have mutilple level. I am trying to click on the menu item using the following code :
[Menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tApo.png)

```js
var component = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gsplitbutton[text="<span class="g-underlined">C</span>ontact"]')[0];

var values = ["New Contact","New Person"];

for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
{ 
   component = component.menu.items.findBy(function(object, id){if(object.text == values[i]) return object; });
} component.getActionEl().dom.click()
```

on Executing this i am getting the following error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined

Also tried component.getEl().dom.click().

Comment: Which menu item would you like to click?

Comment: @Areca Image updated in the question

Comment: The script is able to find the component but while performing the click operation on the menu item it is generating an error

Answer (score 0):

Use `fireEvent` on your component:

```
component.fireEvent("click",component);
```

Comment: it is returning true but not performing the action. A page opens when we perform the click on the menu item

Comment: maybe you are using handler instead of click event. in this case use component.handler(component);

Comment: When i am running it is giving me an error comp.getEl(...) is undefined

Comment: it worked for me. can you provide sencha or js fiddle?

Comment: I'm trying to do this through the java script console, programmatically click it.

Comment: then provide your splitbutton components code and I will check it

Comment: I am trying to automate a website. so i can only access to UI. But additionally i want to mention that component.getEl is coming out to be undefined. That is why i am not able to get its dom property.

Comment: without any code I cannot help you, sorry. at least I need  json structure of splitbutton.

Comment: I will try to get the code behind the split button and then we can discuss

Comment: I found an issue as the last menu was not rendered that's why getActionEl and getEl was not working. the second level menu item get rendered on mouse hovering on its parent menu. Do you know any way by which i simulate that ?

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 6, you can call [`component.onClick(e)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/Item2.html#Ext-menu-Item-method-onClick). This should do exactly what you need.

You would have to hand-craft an object that simulates the expected event object `e`, containing crafted functions for every function that is called from the code, and possibly even some properties.

You would have to sift through the code of your Ext version to see whether there is something comparable available.

Comment: I found an issue as the last menu was not rendered that's why getActionEl and getEl was not working. the second level menu item get rendered on mouse hovering on its parent menu. Do you know any way by which i simulate to show upto n levels of a menu ?